# How to form an HQL query for one to many relationship and grouping one to many

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hql

I need to generate hql query. My table structure is as given below
A -----one to many------> B

and my oracle db query

```
select a.CONF_NUMBER,to_char(max(b.RECEIVE_DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
from A a, B b
where b.RECEIVE_DATE >= to_date('2012-06-07 13:20:28','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') 
group by a.CONF_NUMBER
```

Here I am confused with the fact that how the max(b.RECEIVE_DATE) can be applied
Confused about how the subquery works in HQL

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answers that helped you...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

**DTO**:

```
public interface NumAndDate {
    String getNumber();
    Date getDate();
}
```

**Repository**:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {

     @Query("select a.confNumber as number, max(b.receiveDate) as date from A a join a.b b where b.receiveDate >= ?1 group by a.confNumber")
     List<NumAndDate> getDataByDate(Date date);
}
```

See more info in [JPQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html)